# Cannot use SMTP email sending protocol without errors, in System Settings : Outgoing Email

Tags: email, ee5, settings

I want to get EE's *Outgoing Email* working with the **SMTP Protocol** so that I can tag my messages using an SPF record, to avoid being marked as spam on delivery: https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786

I've tried settings in *System Settings : General Settings : Outgoing Email* for two entirely different SMTP servers without success.

This was tested using the Communicate panel in *Developer : Utilities*.

I'm having to conclude that EE is somehow not passing on correct credentials for sending messages. There's nothing conflicting in *config.php* or *index.php*

**Any other tests I can try?**

## Gmail (G Suite) SMTP Relay

I worked with G Suite Support as far as we could go before they referred me back to EE. A *500 POST* error appeared in the server log for a failed test. Gmail error page was:

> Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8 Username and
> Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u35sm1903136uah.1 -
> gsmtp Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
> configured to send mail using this method.

Relevant EE settings in */cp/settings/email*:

- Address: [G Suite Gmail address]
- Character encoding: UTF-8
- Protocol: SMTP
- Newline character: \r\n
- Server address: smtp-relay.gmail.com
- Server port: 587
- Username: [G Suite Gmail address]
- Password: [application-specific password]
- Connection type: STARTTLS

Gmail SMTP relay service settings:

- Allowed senders: Only addresses in my domains
- Only accept mail from the specified IP addresses: Yes
- Allowed IP addresses: [IP of sending server]
- Require SMTP Authentication: Yes (also tried No)
- Require TLS encryption: Yes

Gmail Allow per-user outbound gateways: On

## VPS hosting provider's SMTP

Also used user/password authentication and STARTTLS.  Error was **403 Forbidden** page.  This triggered the server to block me as a spammer... Once unblocked, same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested with a non-Gmail email account to make sure the EE side is good? I've never had an issue with EE SMTP but never use Gmail.

If that all works it could be something on your server that's getting in the way, might be worth asking your web host to investigate.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've edited the question to show two separate tests. I can understand the host server config interfering with sending, as it did when testing with the host SMTP, but not with Gmail.